# Is there a way to create an urban extent/population distribution map which only includes areas with a population above 100,000

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modis, population, distribution

I'm looking to do analysis on cities throughout the world. I'm using WorldPop, LandScan and MODIS data to gain urban extent and population density maps. I would like to extract areas which have a population size above 100,000. At the moment I think I may have to manually go through each city which has a population of above 100,000 and clip around this to create a new layer, is there another way around this?
I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Please **edit** your question to include the GIS software you are using (including version), and clarify the procedure you think you need to use.  Not much is done "manually" in GIS.

Comment: Thanks Vince, sorry I'm new to asking questions on here, hope the edits I've made helps.

Comment: put a definition query to show only cities that have population above 100,000.

Answer (score 1):

You need a query to select by attributes, and then run your analysis on those selected. Open up the attribute table of the layer that has population information, and note the variable name. Then "Select by Attribute", select the population variable, and type in >100,000. (This is a SQL query; Python is also possible but not necessary for what you're doing.) All the points (=cities) with populations over 100,000 will be highlighted. You can then go back to the layer in your table of contents, right click, and either export as a new shapefile or save as a data layer.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000